# Discord.js embed field counter giving errors

Tags: javascript, discord.js

In my code, I have received the error:

```js
ExpectedConstraintError: Invalid number value
    at Object.run (/home/runner/project/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:702:72)
    at /home/runner/project/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:113:66
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at NumberValidator.parse (/home/runner/project/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:113:29)
    at validateFieldLength (/home/runner/project/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:133:24)
    at EmbedBuilder.addFields (/home/runner/project/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:243:5)
    at /home/runner/project/prefixCommands/viewBoard.js:22:18 {
  constraint: 's.number.lessThanOrEqual',
  given: NaN,
  expected: 'expected <= 25'
}
```

this error occurs if I try to add my first field in my embed. (`embed.addFields({value:"there is nothing here",value:"/u200b"})`)

I have traced the error from these snippets of the discord.js code:

```js
    at EmbedBuilder.addFields (/home/runner/project/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:243:5)
```

is

```js
var EmbedBuilder = class extends UnsafeEmbedBuilder {
  addFields(fields) {
    validateFieldLength(fields.length, this.data.fields);
    return super.addFields(embedFieldsArrayPredicate.parse(fields));
  }
//...
```

and

```
    at validateFieldLength (/home/runner/project/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:133:24)
```

is

```js
var embedFieldPredicate = import_shapeshift.s.object({
  name: fieldNamePredicate,
  value: fieldValuePredicate,
  inline: fieldInlinePredicate
});
var embedFieldsArrayPredicate = embedFieldPredicate.array;
var fieldLengthPredicate = import_shapeshift.s.number.lessThanOrEqual(25);
function validateFieldLength(amountAdding, fields) {
  fieldLengthPredicate.parse((fields?.length ?? 0) + amountAdding);
}
```

Something as simple as this can trigger the error.

```js
client.on(Events.ClientReady, async () => {
    const Embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .addFields{ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },)
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: There is no way around this. You can't have more than 25 fields in a single embed.

Comment: I forgot to add, this happens any time I try, it doesn't work even if it's the first field added.

Comment: Can you show your code please? The compiled djs code you provided isn't all that useful.

Comment: The error can trigger anytime you try to use `.addFields` on an embed constructor.
If you are looking for any other type of code, I'd be glad to include it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on my end. If you can provide a bit more code for context that would be great.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: https://replit.com/@gabegad123/example#index.js is where I got the error. I think there's something going on in the hidden files or something.

Comment: I have an extremely simple setup that just sends a simple embed with one field, and I can decisively say there's no bug in djs. No one can help you if you evade requests for more context.

Comment: It's a weird Repl.it thing and all I had to do was alter the Repl.it files